# Assigning values from one data frame to another based on unique ids in another column

Tags: r

I have two dataframes; dfa and dfb. Dfa contains data on individuals belonging to households, while dfb contains some descriptive statistics on each of those unique households; for example the ratio of bed nets per person (lets call it Netspp). I want to assign the household level information in dfb to each individual belonging to the corresponding household in new columns in dfa, meaning each of the values from dfb may be repeated several times based on how many members are in a given household.

I tried an ifelse statement

```
`dfa$Netspp <- function(dfa) {
   if(dfa$HouseID %in% dfb$HouseID){
      dfb$Netspp
  }
   else NA
 }`
```

But got the error

```
`Error in rep(value, length.out = nrows) : 
  attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'`
```

I also tried

`dfa$Netspp<- dfb$Netspp[dfb$HouseID %in% dfa$HouseID]`

and got this error

```
`Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, "HHMNo", value = c(8L, 4L, 4L, 2L,  : 
  replacement has 382 rows, data has 2356`
```

Hope this makes sense, greatly appreciate any help!

**Solution** merge(dfa, dfb, by.x= HouseID, by.y= HouseID)

Comment: Do you think you can provide a sample of your data? copy the output from `dput(head(dfa))` and `dput(head(dfb))`

Comment: I don't understand why you can't merge them. Won't the merge() function just replicate values for dfb every time it finds a match in dfa?

Comment: ^ this. I don't think I understand your approach to this problem. You are trying to derive Netsapp on the individual level (dfa) but you need the household id which is on dfb?

Comment: I solved the issue as soon as I posted the question (of course), thanks for getting back to me guys! You were right @the_skua. I don't know why I didn't think I could merge them. Still a newbie I guess.